# Retrieve top N rows and sort them by multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-mining

For example, i have `diamonds` dataframe. How can i retrieve **TOP 100 rows sorted by** `price`, `carat` and by size of `x`, `y`, `z`?

I'm used `head(sort=..., n=100)` command, but in such case i cannot use multiple attributes for sorting.

Comment: Maybe this: `diamonds2 <- diamonds[order(diamonds$price,diamonds$carat,diamonds$x,diamonds$y,diamonds$z)[1:100],]`

Comment: console in R studio showing only first 10 (`… with 90 more rows`), how can i view full dataframe?

Comment: Use `View(diamonds2)`

Comment: Yep, now i see, thank you